# xcode publish app icon ERROR ITMS-90709

Tags: xcode

Not sure what's going on - this is my first time using xcode and i keep getting this error when i try to upload my app to the app store.

ERROR ITMS-90709: "Invalid Image Asset. The image asset 'App Icon - Small' in 'Payload/TVO0S.app' is missing an image for the background layer with a scale value of '2'."

I've tried every format/size possible and it still happens. I've even tried downloading a sample project and using the images/icons from that project.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think i fixed that error ... but now im getting this one - ERROR ITMS-90513: "Missing Info.plist Key. Your app's Info.plist must contain the 'CFBundleIcons.CFBundlePrimaryIcon' key."

Comment: how did you manage to fix `ITMS-90709`?